# Assign array keys with array_fill_keys and array_walk

Tags: php, arrays

My problem is, I want to combine two arrays, one containing the header of a table, the other the data. I want to create an associative array with column names as keys. Somehow, I get unexpected results (keys are applied to the wrong array) and can't figure out why.

```
$header = array(array('Name','Position','Salary'));
$data  = array(
    array('John','Manager','30000'),
    array('Cindy','Associate','50000'),
    array('Paul','Staff','20000'),
    array('Mandy','Staff','100000')
    );
array_walk($data, function(&$value, &$key) use ($header) {$value = array_fill_keys($header[0],$value);});
var_dump($data);
```

Here is the link to an online version:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5ad09dbf2c0af5d87f17c64118b9c68a7374a666

What I want to achieve is, that every row from $data has $header[0] as keys.

Regards
Christian

Comment: Related: [PHP How to replace one associative array keys with another array values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36093143/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_shift to up index by 1 along with array_combine,

```
$header = array_shift($header); // to index 1 up    
array_walk($data, function(&$value, &$key) use ($header) {
    $value = array_combine($header,$value);
});
print_r($data);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29d77c65b53159443aa7e613187e65123dc8aa58).

You are using array_fill_keys for the wrong purpose,
here is the [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/341de29db937a819d7475a46b8f0cce4d6c38ab0) of its use.

Answer (score 1):

use `array_combine`

```
array_walk($data, function(&$value, &$key) use ($header) {$value = array_combine($header[0],$value);});
```

[Working example](https://3v4l.org/ofele)